# TFS 2013 Throws Lib2GitSharp Error During Build/Deploy (Intermittent)

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

For a while now, I have been having an issue with Team Foundation Server build/deploy process throwing the following error intermittently:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods' threw an exception. ---> System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.git_threads_init()
at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.LibraryLifetimeObject..ctor()
at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods..cctor()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.RemoveHandle()
at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.LibraryLifetimeObject.Finalize()
Exception Message: MSBuild error 255 has ended this build. You can find more     specific information about the cause of this error in above messages. (type   BuildProcessTerminateException) Exception Stack Trace: at     System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at     System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance,     ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

This problem is very intermittent and it can be bypassed by simply retrying the build. Has anyone else run into this? Any solutions?

Comment: What version of the build agent is this?

Comment: It looks like v5? Basing this off the service URL: /Build/v5.0/Servies

Comment: I'm afraid that's the web service version.  You should try an upgrade to VS 2013 Update 4 if you haven't already, it has many git build updates and bug fixes.

Comment: I just completed the upgrade and received the error again after about 16 builds.

Comment: We're also seeing this error intermittently.  All our TFS servers are running VS/TFS 2013 Update 4.  The msbuild log contains this additional message: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\BuildInfo\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ReleaseManagement.BuildInfo.targets(147,5): warning : The type initializer for 'LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods' threw an exception.

Comment: We also see this about 1 in 10 builds on Visual Studio Online build - there is a suggested workaround [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5a0d1950-1367-41a6-9171-676a0d0e93c1/tfs-online-getted-checkin-build-failures-vs-online-tfs-online-team-need-to-look-into-it?forum=TFService) 'add /p:GenerateBuildInfoConfigFile=false to the msbuild arguments in your build definition' (I have not tried this yet)

Comment: For me this started happening when I change the account the build server was running under, so I would surmise it has something to do with permissions.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I know it is a little bit late for answer but it might help someone else

answer by **Buck Hodges**

We have now gotten to the bottom of this issue after debugging it with Manoj and customer support. It affected gated checkin of continuous delivery of Azure deployments as part of the build process when using the Azure SDK 2.5 or older. The workaround is to add **/p:GenerateBuildInfoConfigFile=false** to the msbuild arguments in your build definition. We are working on updating the build VM in production, but that will take 24-48 hours to propagate to all build pools.

[image: Adding msbuild argument]

You might want to read more in context here
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5a0d1950-1367-41a6-9171-676a0d0e93c1/tfs-online-getted-checkin-build-failures-vs-online-tfs-online-team-need-to-look-into-it?forum=TFService

**Alternative solution based on comments**

If you have VS installed on your build server, make sure you have opened it and licensed it. by [@Phill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330006/phil)

Comment: I actually just got this error by putting /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 in my msbuild arguments for TFS.  removing this line allowed it to work again.

Comment: @Phil i have never seen anyone using that one. As to your condition if you put command specific to vs14 you would need to have the specific dlls available on build server.

Comment: Yeah, i had them (installed VS 2015 enterprise on the box), but apparently  VS 2015 hadn't been opened or licensed.  Once i opened VS 2015 on that box, and logged on with a valid MSDN user, then the builds on that server worked fine, even with that parameter.

Comment: Amazing thnx for sharing your experience

Comment: @Phil how bizarre, I had the same error until I logged into VS2015 on the build server. Thank you for saving me a lot of time!

Comment: The "alternative" solution (logging in to VS online and licensing VS2015) didn't work for me; the only way I could get TFS 2013 to build succesfully using VS 2015 was by adding the parameter to the MSBuild arguments as specified by @cpoDesign.

Comment: I do not understand why this fixed the issue but it has. We had an issue with a build failing intermittently in MSBuild with the following error: "Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods' threw an exception. System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format...." Adding this build parameter has resolved the issue but I still do not understand why it was only affecting this one particular piece of software.

Comment: This answer saved me twice now!  :)

Answer (score 4):

Strangely enough for me, I was getting the same error in the build logs:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\BuildInfo\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ReleaseManagement.BuildInfo.targets (147): The type initializer for 'LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods' threw an exception.
>   Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods' threw an exception. ---> System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

I was able to simply RETRY the build, and it did not fail on the second try. So for me it was a transitory build issue.

Answer (score 0):

Although late to the party, experienced this error recently and while the solution marked as the answer worked for that build, the error was fixed (and the switch removed) when Visual Studio 2012 was upgraded to Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 on the build server which was running TFS 2015 Update 3.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this after I had upgraded my TFS 2013 XAML build machine to TFS 2015.

I had also changed the user that TFS 2015 XAML build used to run the build (service.

The Fix:

I had to log into the TFS 2015 XAML build machine as that new user and launch VS (I was using VS2013).

It ran through it's first time launch questions and setup.

I still saw the Lib2GitSharp Error issue sometimes after that.

Then I also logged VS (on the TFS 2015 XAML build machine) into a valid VS account.

I have not seen the Lib2GitSharp Error since and I never used the /p:GenerateBuildInfoConfigFile=false option.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved this error by adding the build account to the local administrators group on the build machine.

Comment: This is extremely dangerous. Anyone can insert code in the <PostBuildEvent> node of any project which will then get executed under and administrator context. You just gave every developer admin rights on the build machine.