# Cannot find file MSBuild_*.failure.txt

Tags: msbuild, incredibuild

During a long build (started with IncrediBuild), I get error messages like this one:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB4166: Child node "3" exited prematurely. Shutting down. Diagnostic information may be found in files in the temporary files directory named MSBuild_*.failure.txt.
```

Where can I find this file `MSBuild_*.failure.txt`?

**Edit**

According to the comments, I searched in the directory `%TEMP%` for `msbuild`, but I couldn't find any files with the pattern `MSBuild_*.failure.txt`.

Comment: In `%TEMP%`. Type `CD %TEMP%` from a command prompt or `%TEMP%` in the Windows Explorer address bar and hit Enter.

Comment: dupelicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458184/msbuild-log-file-location and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42515424/where-does-msbuild-put-its-failure-log-files  - maybe it's about time someone actually answers this so we can properly mark duplicates. Hint @KenWhite

Comment: I ran into this.  In my situation, the message was a lie, there were definitely no directories or files named *.failure.txt anywhere on the server.  I guess that's why it says "may" be found?  (my problem ended up being this:   https://stackoverflow.com/q/29286052/24267)